# ffmpeg concat: 2nd video stream frozen, no image

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatenate two video streams with the **same econding** into one:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -i parts.txt -c copy join.mkv
```

parts.txt

```
file part1.mkv
file part2.mkv
```

ffmpeg will concatenate them but the playback (any player) gives a still image if the playing position corresponds to the 2nd part.
I tried to switch `part1.mkv` and `part2.mkv` to see the results.
The 1st part (whichever part1 or part2) will play normally but when I seek the playback to the time corresponding the 2nd part the image won't show, only the audio plays.

[image: part1]
[image: part2]
What happens if i seek the playback to the 2nd part:
[image: 2nd part on seeking]

UPDATE:
FULL CONSOLE OUTPUT FOR `ffmpeg -y -f concat -i parts.txt -c copy episode.mkv`

```
ffmpeg version N-81118-gfb91850 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 50.100 / 57. 50.100
  libavformat    57. 44.100 / 57. 44.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 49.100 /  6. 49.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[matroska,webm @ 000000000242bd40] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'parts.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.97 fps, 23.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 1023638
      BPS-eng         : 1023638
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION-eng    : 00:23:17.980000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 33518
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 33518
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 178878340
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 178878340
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.3.1 ('Mask Machine') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.3.1 ('Mask Machine') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-07-30 17:28:29
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-07-30 17:28:29
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 00:22:13.164000000
[matroska @ 0000000000e7c920] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
Output #0, matroska, to 'episode.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.44.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 23.97 fps, 23.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 1023638
      BPS-eng         : 1023638
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION-eng    : 00:23:17.980000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 33518
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 33518
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 178878340
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 178878340
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.3.1 ('Mask Machine') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.3.1 ('Mask Machine') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-07-30 17:28:29
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-07-30 17:28:29
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 00:22:13.164000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[matroska,webm @ 0000000002605dc0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filterpeed=1.87e+003x
frame=56417 fps=47467 q=-1.0 Lsize=  304604kB time=00:39:13.05 bitrate=1060.5kbits/s speed=1.98e+003x
video:304191kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.135798%
```

Comment: Show the full console output for the ffmpeg command.

Comment: There you go. Full console output added to the question.

Comment: How did you generate these parts?

Comment: I didn't. I get them as they are.